# Java maximum printing doubles and ints

Tags: java, printing, int, double, max

I have a max function that takes 5 inputs and prints the maximum depending on what the user entered. For example:

Input: 1 2 3 2.4 0.2

Output: 3 (int)

or

Input: 1.7 2 3 4.0 3.2

Output: 4.0 (double)

I can't figure out what to do. An error occurs in the second case when 4.0 == 4. How do I bypass that?

```
max=(double) i;
    System.out.print(" "+i);
            if (Math.round(max) == max) {
                System.out.print(Math.round(max));
            } else {
                System.out.print(max);
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your loop running over the string representation of the numbers, just keep both the string that was largest, and its parsed double value. Then at the end just print the string corresponding to the largest value.

```
    double max = -Double.MAX_VALUE;
    String smax = null;
    for (String s: args) {
        double d = Double.parseDouble(s);
        if (d > max) {
            smax = s;
            max = d;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(smax);
```

Comment: Ty, but how would I do this without String ?

Comment: If you are presented with a Collection<Number> you can just keep the Number instead. You didn't tell what your input consisted of.

Comment: I know I should be more precise but I found the way :). The input is only numbers(double or ints)